# Call ASMX web service with parameter and get value from that web service?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm a new in c# and very beginner,need to call this web service in c# windows application:

```
http://192.168.200.102:8086/ws_bills.asmx
```

for that purpose i right click on the solution explorer and add web service with `behzadService` name and try write code for call that:

```
behzadService.WS_Bills beh = new behzadService.WS_Bills();
```

But i want call this url with that code:

[image]

How can i write c# code for send `UserName,Password,TelNo,Cycle`?
And my other question that web service return me this:

[image]

How can i parse `TelNo,CurrBill,TotalBill` with that call?

Please write code.
that web service result is this:
[image]

Comment: Is this webservice is made by you?

Comment: No,that made with other person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote web service return table

```
behzadService.WS_Bills beh = new behzadService.WS_Bills();
DataSet dsResult = beh.GetBills("Username", "Password", "12565855555", "A");
DataTable dtResult = dsResult.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataRow row in dtResult.Rows)
        {
            long telNo = Convert.ToInt64(row["Telno"]);
            decimal curBill = Convert.ToDecimal(row["CurBill"]);
            decimal totalBill = Convert.ToDecimal(row["TotalBill"]);
        }
```

Comment: Not at all.   Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can call webservice by calling `GetBills` function

```
behzadService.WS_Bills beh = new behzadService.WS_Bills();
var result = beh.GetBills("Shahzad","1233","021344444444","any value");
```

after that check what result will come in result.
and let me know

Comment: thanks for answer,in this var result = beh.GetBills("Shahzad","1233","021344444444","any value"); line i get this:Path property must be set before calling the Send method.
error.what happen?

Comment: This means your WSDL file has no destination defined.

Comment: Ok solve that error,that web service call successfully,now how can i parse that result ?

Comment: can you give fake result which will come in result variable?

Comment: i update my question ,and upload my result,please review

Comment: will you please give text instead of image?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote parse result.

```
behzadService.WS_Bills beh = new behzadService.WS_Bills();
var result = beh.GetBills("Username","Password","0012565855555","A");
long telNo = Convert.ToInt64(result.Telno,0);
decimal curBill = Convert.ToDecimal(result.CurBill,0);
decimal totalBill= Convert.ToDecimal(result.TotalBill,0);
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but result.Telno not known,just know result.Table,i this that web service return table .

Comment: I add a new answer that web service return table. Pls check it